# Approximating Integral

Tags: calculus

First let me start out saying that I am looking for an approximation as  we have not yet learned to find exact integral values.

The question states:

Find the area between the curve $y=\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$ and the x-axis, for -2 <= x <= 1. Round the answer to three decimal places.

My first question is, for the given problem is this the correct format as how I am suspose to write the equation:

$$\int_{-2}^1\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}dx$$

secondly for my solution I came up with the answer: 1.434

Could someone please check this for me and tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Bx%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29%2C+%28x%2C-2%2C1%29

Comment: If it's the area you need to find, then you ought to use the absolute value $\frac{|1+x|}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @AndreySokolov As the graph of f(x) will be negative until x=-1. Thanks for spotting that. Which should put my answer at 1.707

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the facts that

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \arctan{x}$$
$$\int dx \frac{x}{1+x^2} = \frac12 \log{(1+x^2)}$$

to get that

$$\int_{-2}^1 dx \frac{1+x}{1+x^2} = \arctan{1} + \arctan{2} + \frac12 \log{\frac{2}{5}} \approx 1.4344 $$

For a positive area calculation, however, the integral looks like

$$-\int_{-2}^{-1} dx \frac{1+x}{1+x^2} + \int_{-1}^{1} dx \frac{1+x}{1+x^2} = 3 \arctan{1}-\arctan{2} - \frac12 \log{\frac{2}{5}} \approx 1.7072$$